# C# How to remove element from the regular array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I am using a regular array which has 5 elements I want to remove the element but I don't want to use any collection such as `arrayList` or `List`

My code is

```
for (int c = 0; c < Alpha.Length; c++)
{
    if (Alpha[c].Power< 0)
    {
      //  Alpha.s = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use `List<T>` instead?

Comment: You can't remove element from regular array. All you can - assign some value to element, or create new array and copy all other items there. That's why collections are handy

Comment: You want to remove an item and sort the others, so the array dont get null values on is middle?

Answer (score 10):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx)

> The number of dimensions and **the length** of each dimension are
>   established when the array instance is created. These values can't be
>   changed during the lifetime of the instance.

(Emphasis mine).

Arrays, by design, have a fixed size in C#, so a new array should be allocated:

```
Alpha = Alpha.Where(a => a.Power >= 0).ToArray();
```

Without Linq:

```
TheType[] alpha2 = new TheType[Alpha.Length];
int j=0;
for (int i=0; i < Alpha.Length; i++)
    if(Alpha[i].Power >= 0)
    {
        alphaTmp[j++] = Alpha[i];
    }
Array.Resize(ref alphaTmp, j);
Alpha = alphaTmp;
```

Comment: It will create new array with proper elements. But because you can't change array size without recreating it I think it's really a good way to go here (but using `List<T>` would be better anyway).

Comment: There is no use of collections here. There is only the use of linq.

Comment: @user2740970 Not LINQ either? You certainly have strict (and strange) requirements.

Comment: thats the problem no linq and collection otherwise i would have used List<>

Comment: What version of .Net are you targeting?

Answer (score 6):

You can't "remove" an element from an array in terms of any operation which changes the length of the array: once an array has been created, its length is fixed. Options:

- Change the element value to null, or some other appropriate value
- Shift all the other elements towards the head and set the *last* element value to null etc
- Create a new array with a smaller length, potentially assigning it back to the variable/property which originally referred to the larger array

It's unclear *why* you're rejecting the normal collections though. You should think about this decision *very* carefully - using the built-in collection types is almost *always* a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ:

```
Alpha = Alpha.Where(ob => bo.Power >= 0).ToArray();
```

Remember - it will create a new array.

BTW. Why you don't want to use `List<T>`?

Comment: i dont want to use collection and linq